# Error from consent controller while building quickstart UI in identity server 4

Tags: visual-studio, identityserver4, asp.net-core-1.1

I am trying to add UI over my implementation of IdentityServer4, I am following the documentation quickstart guide https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html and I have copied folders from the release repo
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release
When I try to build this solution on visual studio I get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IResourceStore' does not contain a definition for 'FindEnabledResourcesByScopeAsync' and no extension method 'FindEnabledResourcesByScopeAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IResourceStore' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   TrialAuthentication..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1    C:\Users\admin\trial-authentication\Controllers\ConsentController.cs    121 Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's a new release candidate for IdentityServer4 - and the latest version of the UI for download reflects that. Meanwhile, the documentation still references rc4.

Just go to project.json and replace

```
"IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc4-update1"
```

with

```
"IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc5"
```

And your projects will compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's fixed my problem